# Bootstrap datepicker is setting current date whenever i am clicking on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, datepicker

I am using bootstrap date-picker with knockout, but it's not working properly. Whenever I click anywhere on my `html` page it's calling datepicker set value and sets current date.

Please let me know how to prevent this to call set value till I select date from date picker control.

This is what I am doing.

```
<div class="control-group">
    <span class="control-label lblWidth">Start Date:</span>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="input-append date" data-date="dateValue:Project.sDate">
            <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" data-bind="value:Project.sDate" readonly="readonly" />
            <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
   <span class="control-label lblWidth">End Date:</span>
   <div class="btn-group">
       <div class="input-append date" data-date="dateValue:Project.eDate">
           <input class="span2" size="16" type="text" data-bind="value:Project.eDate" readonly="readonly" />
           <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in JavaScript:

`$('.date').datepicker();`

Answer (score 1):

Try that code : 
`$('.date').datepicker('update',required_date);`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem just now. Although I don't know the origin of the problem I was able to fix the problem by downloading the latest version of bootstrap datepicker (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and updating/replacing the *bootstrap-datepicker.js* file.